# Using bulk actions with AsyncElasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm using fastapi with `elasticsearch-py` client version `8.11.1`. I want to use `AsyncElasticsearch` class to implement seach, update, ... actions asynchronously. I want to use `helpers.actions.bulk` function of this library but it doesn't accept `AsyncElasticsearch` client. (It accepts regular `Elasticsearch` client).
How can I implement bulk actions with this elasticsearch client asynchronously?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a separate set of helpers that work with AsyncElasticsearch https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.11.1/async.html#async-helpers